# Abstract Algebra proof about Rings that contain functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

Let $T_{[0,1]}$ denote the ring of all functions $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $T_{[0,2]}$ denote the ring of all functions $f: [0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Are they isomorphic?

I assumed they are, since I cannot think of a reason they wouldn't be. I denoted a function f $f:T_{[0,1]} \rightarrow T_{[0,2]}$ to be a function where for $t_{[0,1]}(x)$, $f(t_{[0,1]}(x)) = t_{[0,2]}(2x)$. I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Would the function f(x) = 2x, where x is in $T_{[0,1]}$ be a better start?

Comment: That's actually a function $T_{[0,2]}\to T_{[0,1]}$.

Comment: Just show that $f$ is a ring homomorphism whose kernel is the $0$ function and whose range is $T_{[0, 2]}$.  The easiest way to handle the latter part is to show that $f^{-1}$ is $1-1$ with range contained in $T_{[0, 1]}$.  @MattSamuel is correct that you are working backwards.  You want to use $\frac x2$, not $2x$.

Comment: Can you prove that if $X\cong Y$ then $T_X\cong T_Y$?

Comment: @MPW What are X and Y?

Comment: @MPW I think I see what you're saying. I don't know if I can prove that

Comment: @JohnMancini : I was thinking topological spaces. But I also thought this was the ring of *continuous* functions, so maybe my comment doesn't make sense in retrospect. But I think  it makes sense to say that if $X$ and $Y$ are any two sets, then $|X|=|Y|$ implies $T_X\cong T_Y$

Comment: @MPW I don't know if I can justify that for this proof. If I could think of the function that maps elements in $T_{[0,1]}$ to $T_{[0,2]}$ then this would be easier to prove.

Comment: Pick your favorite bijection $\phi:X\to Y$. Show that the map $f\mapsto f\circ \phi$ is an isomorphism $T_X\to T_Y$ (i.e., show it is 1-1, onto, preserves ring structure).

Comment: @MPW so find a bijection g from [0,1] to [0,2]. Then show that a function from f to $f \circ g$ is an isomorphism for $T_{[0,1]} \rightarrow T_{[0,2]}$? I think that's too advanced for me

Comment: I wanted to add a comment on a question you just deleted: Much of mathematics has the property that a slight change to a problem formulation can dramatically change the problem difficulty. It is normal to feel overwhelmed when dealing with new stuff.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you! I deleted it because I realize it was more of a vent than a question. But thank you for saying that. I will never give up!